# Can polyjuice potion allow a user to bypass apparation restrictions?

Tags: harry-potter

In the sixth film, it's revealed that Dumbledore is able to apparate within Hogwarts' grounds.

> Harry Potter: But, Sir, I thought we weren't allowed to apparate on Hogwarts' grounds.
>
> Albus Dumbledore: Well, being me... has its privileges.

Does Polyjuice potion effect apparation restrictions? If a Deatheater, or anyone else for that matter, was to disguise as Dumbledore, would they be able to appare within Hogwarts? Or, the other way round: if Dumbledore was to disguise as someone else, would he then be unable to apparate within the Hogwarts grounds?

Comment: That's not a quote from the book, as far as I'm aware. Question is founded on an incorrect premise: Dumbledore can't apparate to, from or within Hogwarts without lifting the anti-apparition spells in place.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Much as it may pain purists, the movies do exist and contribute to the canon, even if it parts of that contribution only pertains to the movie universe. Within that movie universe the premise for the question is solid, as we never see him lifting or otherwise negating the apparation protections.

Comment: I would assume that Dumbledore had at least a hand in the anti-apparition charms. He knows about Polyjuice, so I assume that wouldn’t be sufficient – cf Fred and George’s Aging Potion in *Goblet of Fire*.

Comment: Because the films are nonsense?

Comment: I would say no; if Aging potion doesn't get past the Age line, polyjuice won't work on the jinx.

Comment: @xantec there are so many unreconcilable differences between the books and films, that in my opinion they *must* be considered separate canons. the movies are a disgrace to the book canon—it's disappointing to see so many questions focused on the movies on this site, when the movies don't explain much at all about the universe. the books are VERY different.

Comment: i always figured he meant "being me" as in "being an incredibly crafty and powerful wizard" rather than "being the headmaster".  as such, he simply meant he knew how to defeat the anti-apparation charm rather than that he was exempt.  sort of like the hulk responding "it's good to be me" when someone says "most people can't walk through walls"

Comment: The movie's cheat is grounded in powerful possibility: 12 Grimmauld Place. They were able to apparate to the porch to prevent being seen entering. It's entirely possible that Dumbledore through a clever combination of charms arranged to do something quite similar. Have some secret places where he could apparate from. And of course, it seems entirely possible he was aware of magic that wasn't shared on screen or page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### In the books, Dumbledore Apparated from Hogsmeade

> A minute later they turned the corner into the side street where 
>   the Hog’s Head’s sign creaked a little, though there was no breeze. 
>   In contrast to the Three Broomsticks, the pub appeared to be com-
>   pletely empty.
>
> “It will not be necessary for us to enter,” muttered Dumbledore, 
>   glancing around. “As long as nobody sees us go . . . now place your 
>   hand upon my arm, Harry. There is no need to grip too hard, I am 
>   merely guiding you. On the count of three . . . One . . . two . . . 
>   three . . .”

However, even in the movies, the answer is probably...

### No

Many kinds of magic can recognize someone under the influence of Polyjuice potion. The Marauder's Map is not fooled. Dementors perceive emotions, not faces, and thus probably see through such disguises.

It seems likely that the spells recognize the headmaster, not whether someone looks like the headmaster.

I trust that Dumbledore knows what he's saying: "*Being* me has its privileges."

Comment: Also of note is that Dumbledore is an above-average wizard with the Elder Wand, which means he can perform some pretty impressive magic (and presumably bypass restrictions that your average wizard cannot).

Comment: Another example of magic being pretty smart about detecting things is in book four when the weasly twins age themselves to enter the competition but it doesn't work properly.